# Windows could not start the SQL Server service (SQLEXPRESS) service on local computer

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows 10 (64-bit). My server name is `SRIDHARAN-PC` and I gave it correctly and I got an error like:

> A network related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL server.

And when I go for `services.msc` and start the SQL Server service, I get an error like

> Windows could not start the SQL Server service (SQLEXPRESS) service on local computer
>
> The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Check the event viewer for additional information

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 is not supported on Windows 10, but it does not means if already installed this will stop SQL Server from coming online. Please look at event viewer for more information